# My glasses has "prescription?" (comparing with fashion glasses) What is a better/correct term?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

I know you can say prescription glasses but how do you say it in this sentence:

My eyeglasses has ______.

My eyeglasses is _______.

if you want to compare it with fashion eyeglasses (regular lenses not for shortsightedness or farsightedness)

In my country we call it "grado" (grade) and "walang grado" (no grade)

*Ang salamin ko ay may grado.* = My eyeglasses has *grado.*

Some people from my country incorrectly say

"My eyeglasses has a grade. / My eyeglasses are graded." / "I have graded eyeglasses."

Is it okay to say "My eyeglasses has/have prescription."

Comment: 'My glasses are prescribed.' 'I have a prescription for glasses.' The prescription is for the patient, it prescribes what glasses are required. And prescription glasses can still be fashionable since the glass is prescribed but the frames can be as fancy as one wants. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: And non-prescription  glasses (people don't use 'eyeglasses' as often) are also available for shortsightedness at least.

Comment: My glasses are prescriptivist

Comment: @EdwinAshworth good point, I for one wear off-the-shelf (non-prescribed) reading glasses.  So there's two main categories - glasses that are purely cosmetic and others that have lenses.  Within the lensed category there's prescription and off-the-shelf.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comments. What I meant here is eyeglasses for nearsightedness or farsightedness as opposed to glasses with regular lenses. It's a fashion trend here to wear eyeglasses and some people look down on it lol People always ask me if my eyeglasses are prescription glasses.

Comment: Mr. @EdwinAshworth Oh, I have never  seen over-the-counter glasses for shortsightedness here in my place. I only see reading glasses in drugstores. 
What I actually mean with fashion glasses are the ones with regular lenses and not for any vision problems, just purely cosmetic like what Mr. MaxWilliams said.

Answer (score 3):

You could say (prescribed is used as an adjective to describe the eyeglasses):

> My eyeglasses are prescribed (by an optometrist).

Or you could say ([*prescription glasses* is a plural noun](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prescription-glasses)):

> I have prescription eyeglasses.

You cannot say:

> My eyeglasses have prescription.
>
> My eyeglasses has prescription.
>
> My eyeglasses is prescribed

Comment: Although you can say "my glasses are prescription."